# Central Limit Theorem with Volume

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Suppose are growing limes. Suppose the mean radius of the limes is 9cm with standard
deviation 2 cm.
Suppose a bar who will buy our limes expects the volume of the limes to be between 8π
cm3 and 12π cm3. If they will buy 6 dozen limes, what is the probability the sample
mean volume will be in this range?
I am stack with volume, thinking to use volume of sphere to find radius. Please help.

Comment: Are you growing limes or melons?  $9$ cm is not a realistic radius for a lime.  A sphere of radius $9$ has a volume of $972\pi$.  There must be some mistake in the data.

Comment: It is not mistake. My question is can I use volume of sphere for limes? We are studying CLT

Comment: I don't know what else you'd use.  Some limes are roughly spherical.  That's really a question for your instructor.